# There is Unmarshalling error message when try to deploy spring-war to websphere?

Tags: java, spring, websphere

There is application on spring 4.1+maven. Needs to deploy from web-interface web-sphere this application.

my pom.xml

```
<groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
        <jackson.xml>2.9.7</jackson.xml>
        <jackson.core>2.9.6</jackson.core>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>test</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
    </build>
```

My Init class for application, nameed WebInitalizer

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ru.sbrf.risks.services.data"})
public class WebAppInitalizer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(
                WebConfig.class
        );

        FilterRegistration charEncodingfilterReg = servletContext.addFilter("CharacterEncodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);
        charEncodingfilterReg.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        charEncodingfilterReg.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        charEncodingfilterReg.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
    }
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
    public String healthCheck() {
        return "Status OK";
    }
}
```

and webConfig

```
@Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"web"})
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
    public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
                DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.enable();
        }

        @Override
        public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry) {

        }

        @Override
        public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
            converters.add(new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter());
            converters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
            converters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter());
        }

        @Bean
        public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
            RequestMappingHandlerMapping mhm = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
            //suffix parser is off for urls like .../search/timeKey.key:some_key
            mhm.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
            return mhm;
        }
    }
```

But there is error - message when try to deploy war to webspere application server:

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590)
        ... 117 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException
        at ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.web.WebConfig.configureMessageConverters(WebConfig.java:43)

Comment: You might want a few more of those dependencies to be `provided`. At least activation and maybe jaxb. WebSphere does typically include those things... And do you actually need the Sun-specific artifacts? Are you trying to build for multiple different Java EE servers? Also, which version of WebSphere?